# Get top-frame (address bar in browser) URL in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, url, frame

I'm sorry for my English, it isn't so good...
I need help with a simple PHP program: if the page's URL contain a specific word, the content is showed. If there isn't it, the entire page redirects. I would use this to prevent me from frames that other webmasters make to "steal" my website contents.
For this is ok.. But a friend of mine need to make a black list of specific words, not a white list. So if the URL contain a word, the entire page redirects. I tried using *$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']* but if the "thief" put the frame on an external website that is not in the black list and after he make a frame of the frame, the content is showed and the page doesn't redirect.. 
So I think it's like that: *$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']* could read just 1st level frame and not the main page (top frame).
I really need help with this, I can't make it with Javascript because we want to keep the code not visible.

If it is not possible, is there a method to pass a JS variable value to a PHP variable for my case?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: ...pass a JS variable value to a PHP variable...

Like ajax?

Comment: If you Google "php get url", you will get a ton of results that tell you how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible by javascript if and only if the top level domain is the same as yours. If that is the case, you could make an ajax call to the server, passing along the url and then the server could determine whether or not to redirect.

Instead of showing what the code would look like, I'm much more inclined to persuade you against this approach. If you have content that you don't want people to steal, you should make your site non-public (i.e. users must login). If that is not possible, the content that you are worried about sounds like it shouldn't be on the internet.

Comment: I prepared the AJAX but I don't know how to use Javascript to identify the main frame URL.. top.location.href, if the page is in a frame, gives me "undefined" value.. any suggestions? is top.location.href correct to know the window url?

Comment: @rickrack that is only correct if the iframe and the top window have the same domain. For example, the iframe has src="example.com/something" and the top level window is also at example.com.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So it's impossible to get the main URL with PHP or Javascript??

Comment: It sounds like you know that you will not be iframed into the same domain. So no, you cannot get the top level url from either the client-side or the server-side. HTTP_REFERER can be changed by the caller and therefore cannot be trusted. Javascript won't let you communicate in a cross-domain fashion for security reasons.